# Is it possible to have more than one private/public key pair per user for SSH?

Tags: ssh

I need a user with more than one key-pair for SSH. Is that possible? Is that possible without having to specify which key to use on each command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can have multiple SSH keys (multiple identities). To use the at the command line add a `-i` option, e.g.

```
ssh -i .ssh/id_dsa_host_1 host_1
```

If you have a key for each server you can add the info in the .ssh/config file (see `man ssh_config` for details), e.g.

```
Host host_1
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa_host_1

Host host_2
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa_host_2
```

Comment: `ssh-agent` can also be used to add multiple keys.